# Intellij Regexsearch not working properly

Tags: regex, search, intellij-idea

I want to search every occurence of `main.` and replace it with an empty string. The expression `\b^main\.` is working in my tests but doesn't find any occurences in my files. Do I need to modify the expression in order to make it work?

Comment: Using `\b` with `^` doesn't make sense what are you trying to match ? If `main.` is at the beginning of the string then remove `\b`.

Comment: I am looking for a word that starts with `main.` the text doesn't start with the word.

Comment: Then just get ride of `^`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex pattern

```
\bmain[.]
```

or

```
\bmain\.
```

Special character `^` represents a beginning of the line or string and it should not be part of your regex pattern. Special character `\b` represents a word boundary and this is all you need to have infront of `main` string. Because dot `.` represents any character in regex, you need to escape it or put in into square brackets `[]`, so it represents just real dot/period character.